# How to make my script wait till the previous command completes?

Tags: multithreading, perl, installation

I have the following Perl script code to install oracle DB application.

```
system("./runInstaller -silent -responsefile filename.rsp");
if($?==0)
{
   //perform some operation type1;
}
else
{
   //perform some operation type2;
}
```

In this code the execution of if block should be performed after the complete installation of the application. But the script runs parallel to the installer.

I have used both **``** and **exec** instead of system, but none works as needed.

Help me in solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps installer goes to background?

Comment: Maybe runInstaller is returning immediately?

Comment: Nope, the runInstaller is working on the foreground.

Comment: `system` waits for the process it creatures to exit before returning. That means `runInstaller` is returning before you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using of -waitforcompletion option of runInstaller makes the script to wait till it complete execution. So now:

```
system("./runInstaller -silent -responseFile filename.rsp");
```

will become

```
system./runInstaller -silent -waitforcompletion -responseFile filename.rsp");
```

For more info on runInstaller [Click here](http://www.oracle-wiki.net/startdocsruninstaller)